# Add and grant NTAUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE login to a SQL 2000 database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create a script for CI/deployment purposes, but am having problems. Unfortunately, I'm having to use SQL 2000, which is outside of my comfort zone.

Seemingly, CREATE USER ... FOR LOGIN is not supported, so I have to use sp_addlogin and sp_adduser.

I need to grant permission for the NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE user:

```
EXEC sp_addlogin N'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'
EXEC sp_adduser N'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'
```

However, this doesn't work, as the sp_addlogin call returns the error:

> 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' is not
>   a valid name because it contains
>   invalid characters.

So how can I make this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not tested this in SQL Server 2000 but I think you should use [sp_grantlogin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933411%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) instead of [sp_addlogin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259567%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) to give windows users access SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks Mikael. This worked. Am using: EXEC sp_grantlogin N'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE';exec sp_grantdbaccess  N'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'